# localhost:4200 not working for my angular app

Tags: node.js, angular

Till yesterday, everything was working good. Using cmd, I type ng serve, go to my browser type localhost:4200 and my website fires up.
Suddenly today, the localhost is not responding. The ng serve is working properly.

Output after typing ng-serve-

```
10% building 3/3 modules 0 activei ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://localhost:4200/webpack-dev-server/
i ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from /
i ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to //index.html

chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 47.8 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.js, polyfills.js.map (polyfills) 264 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {runtime} runtime.js, runtime.js.map (runtime) 6.15 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.js, styles.js.map (styles) 9.7 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 3.81 MB [initial] [rendered]
Date: 2019-09-05T04:20:41.402Z - Hash: a7331d4e748902ef88b7 - Time: 19033ms
** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
```

I tried different browsers, tried reinstalling angular, still the problem persists.

The message that I get on my browser is - This site can't be reached.

Comment: What do you get(logs) in your command line when you run `ng serve`? You will need to provide more details for us to help you.

Comment: Try run "ng serve --verbose" to see more log detail and tell us more about it

Comment: @PrameshBajracharya the same thing I get everyday - mentioned it in the question.

Comment: @peterzinho16 there's too much info. harmony import export specifiers

Comment: try to change port `ng serve --port 4400`

Comment: @piyushjain I get the same error

Comment: Have you project in github to see detail?

Comment: By any chance are you using Google analytics? If yes make sure its loading async...

Comment: can you do iisreset and try to give ng serve again?

Comment: @SiddharthVinze May be try `ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 9456`? Changing host and port?

Answer (score 8):

You can try changing your host and your port, something like this:

```
ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 5000
```

Maybe it will help...

Answer (score 3):

With **ng serve** instead of opening the URL with **http://localhost:4200** open with **http://0.0.0.0:4200** .

Answer (score 2):

Ok I found the problem. 
After Windows Update, the Firewall Settings were messed up. I restored the default settings and now it's working fine.
Moral of the Story: Use Linux!

Answer (score 0):

If <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> is typed to copy the URL http://localhost:4200 or for any other purpose then in the browser it shows `Site cannot be reached`. To resolve this one can execute `ng serve` command again and reload the browser without typing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying in chrome and getting the ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR check if your chrome browser is forcing the `http` requests to `https`.
To verify this case check the application by running it in Incognito mode.
If this is the case then try to reset it by going to `chrome://net-internal/#hsts` and Deleting the domain security policy.

If you want a temporary solution then just run it in incognito mode.

Answer (score -1):

Before starting your app making every time first compile.

Steps.

1. Go to your file location in CMS.
2. And type `ng serve` and wait.
3. Then go to `localhost:4200`